# emacs & and accidental fg

Tags: bash, emacs

This is on Linux(RHEL, kbunutu, and Mint - all KDE if that makes any difference). I do this fairly often, I start emacs from a terminal window like

```
 $> emacs &
```

then later I accidentally do

```
 $> fg
```

now my terminal won't do anything unless I do Ctrl-Z but doing that makes the emacs window stop responding until I do another fg.  Is there some way to send emacs back to the background and keep the emacs window responding?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah.  Use `bg` (after <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>z</kbd>, i. e. when you can enter commands like that `fg`) to send it back to the background ;-)

See this diagram for an overview of which action leads to which state:

[image: State chart of Unix process states]

(Diagram taken from http://minnie.tuhs.org/CompArch/Labs/week8.html.)

Comment: Well you should point out that you have to do Ctrl-Z and then bg as just doing bg doesn't do anything.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I did that.